# Regex to fetch string including only digits

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm making a script to extract specified strings from a source code. The string may contain word and symbols. For example

```
a = "xyz" //1: loading.setText( "#{100}" );
```

I want to extract

```
"#{100}"
```

My [regex](http://rubular.com/r/nJjkThFL5B) is wrong, it takes out `" //1: loading.setText( "`.

Comment: [this is what you want](http://rubular.com/r/WrzavkNVAO). Note, you were having `"` before and at the end of your regex. Which was starting the match after the first `"`. You don't need them. Also, You don't need your last `?`, as you are already using *negated character class*.

Comment: @RohitJain Thank you. But it contains `//1: loading.setText(` too. How to exclude that?

Comment: If you just want `"#{100}"`, then just use `["]#{\d+}["]`.

Comment: @RohitJain No, I'm just take this as an example. May be `"#{100}"`, `@100` or anything else.

Comment: This is one way to do it, if you want to extract **one** string after `//`: http://rubular.com/r/DQrZnBagbu

Answer (score 1):

This will [get you what you want](http://rubular.com/r/VbJZifwuX8):

```
loading\.setText\( ([^ ]+) )
```

It's the match group you are after.

if you don't want the quotes...

loading.setText( "([^"]+)" )

but it may not suffice - you have not explained what the variable patterns are in your sample string, so I guessed. If this doesn't work for you, you need to define your case better. What is the surrounding pattern that defines the data you want to extract? What is the defining pattern of the data itself?